# ReactJS one time initialisation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I have a Component say HomePage where I'm calling `getCurrentLocation` to get the location using GPS. This value will be used to select a value from a Drop Down. User may then use the dropdown to change the value.

When I navigate away from this page and then come back using

```
const appHistory = createHashHistory();
appHistory.goBack();
```

the constructor and the componentDidMount are executed again. So the user selected value is lost and i get the default value again.

So where do I put by initialisation code? I come from Ionic where there something like [ionViewDidLoad](https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/) which is executed only when the page loads the first time. Is there an equivalent for this is React.

Below is my code

```
export class HomePage extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
state = {
        currentLocationCoordinates:[],
    };
this.getCurrentLocation = this.getCurrentLocation.bind(this);
}

getCurrentLocation(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((success)=>{
            console.log("Current Location: "+success.coords);
            this.setState({
                currentLocationCoordinates:[success.coords.latitude,success.coords.longitude],
                userLocationCoordinates:[success.coords.latitude,success.coords.longitude]
            });
        });
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
        this.getCurrentLocation();
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using `componentDidMount` for this. Make your components as resilient to re-renders and re-mounts as possible.

By the sounds of it you are after an application level *state container* that will hold your application state regardless of whether your component is mounted or not.

Most of the React community relies on [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts) for this although other state containers *do exist*. I'd suggest having a look at Redux and using it to hold those location details as part of Redux store. They will then be always accessible on your component as props, regardless of whether it re-renders or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ComponentDidMount()` together with a flag that detects whether the component has been initialized or not. You are on the right track.

```
componentDidMount(){
        initialized ? "" : this.getCurrentLocation();
}
```